# packge or folder with files in android studio

Tags: java, android, file

I try to manage files in android, but I dont know where put this files to manage in execution.

[image: Where i can put prueba.html to access this file in execution?]

Where I can put prueba.html to access this file in execution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create new assets folder inside app folder.
put html files in assets folder.
for access files use "file:///android_asset/index.html"

Answer (score 0):

To access a file Put file in asstes folder

To create asstes folder Goto File -> New -> Folder -> Assets Folder

Comment: And where is the path to access to this assets folder in execution?

Comment: file:///android_asset/prueba.html

Comment: when i try File archivos =  new File("file:///android_asset/"); , show me NullPointerExecption